# MAX6675 k-type thermocouple ADC is giving high readings

Tags: temperature, troubleshooting, thermocouple, calibration

I have designed and built a small fairly simple circuit that uses a MAX6675 chip to take temperature readings from a multiplexed array of 16 k-type thermocouples.

Datasheets:

MAX6675: https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2079272.pdf

Thermocouple: https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1918816.pdf

For the channel multiplexing I'm using a pair of MAX4544EUT+T and a CD4051BM96  (the latter is definitely a CMOS device, not sure about the former).

The system basically works from end-to-end.  The data output from the MAX6675 is coherent and well formatted.  However the actual temperatures indicated by the data are too high.

The circuit board and the thermocouples are just sitting at ambient temperature on my desk (about 19 Celsius at the moment).  Yet I'm getting readings in the region of 47 Celsius from the MAX6675.  This is far higher than the typical error rates suggested in the MAX6675's datasheet.

I believe that the firmware in the microcontroller is reading the data correctly, as it does properly identify "open" circuits for those channels where no thermocouple has been attached.  The values do change if I touch one of the thermocouple junctions with my hand (ramping up quickly and then ramping down again when I let go).  So fundamentally it is all working.

**What could be the cause of this ~28 degree offset in the readings?**

28 degrees is equivalent to 112 LSBs counts on the MAX6675's ADC!

I did wonder if it would be the extra resistance in the circuit because of the multiplexing chips, but this additional 160 Ohms is negligible compared to the 60,000 Ohm thermocouple input impedance on the MAX6675.

I think that the readings coming from the device should be absolute temperatures (e.g. any compensation for the cold junction is done by the MAX6675 internally), and do not need any further compensation in software.

The circuit itself does not warm up appreciably with prolonged use (no more than ambient + 4 degrees on top of the MAX6675 package measured with a Fluke meter).  I don't think this is the cause of the discrepancy, as the readings are wrong by the same amount even when the board is starting from ambient temp.

The data format presented by the MAX6675 is shown on page 6 of the datasheet.

Consequently my readings of `0x05f8` for instance resolve to 47.75 Celsius.

To convert: right-shift the raw value by 3 bits, convert to float then multiply by 0.25 to get the temperature in Celsius.

Is this behaviour something I should simply be compensating for by calibrating my system with a compensation value?  The datasheet doesn't mention anything about having to do that.

Comment: What is the multiplexer?

Comment: I tend to agree w/@tobalt that multiplexing might be the problem.  Can you directly connect a thermocouple bypassing the multiplexer and post the results?  Also, you did not mention the cold joint.  Did you take care that the point of contact is only 1 type of metal (i.e. if soldered to the PCB, for example, you may be touching the copper trace or you may not be touching the copper trace).

Comment: @tobalt, I've added the part numbers for the muxes.  Both of those seem to have leakage in the order of nanoamps at the kind of temperatures I'm working at.

Comment: @st2000, the cold-junction seems to be entirely within the package body and there is no exposed thermal pad on the underside of the package.  All pins are well soldered to their pads, inspected visually and with a meter.  Stupidly, I designed this board so that the mux chips are always enabled, I'll have to life a pin on the 1-of-2 mux to isolate the analog input to the ADC, then I'll try connecting a thermocouple directly to the ADC.

Comment: It could easily be the current from the open thermocouple detector developing a drop on the MUX resistance. We have approx 30K×40uV/K=1.2mV offset which would turn into 1.2mV/160ohm=7uA detector bias current, it sounds possible. I'd check the datasheet and/or try removing the MUX.

Comment: Cross-talk with the multiplexer ...

Comment: @Antonio51, I don't think it's that.  The ADC is not sampling while the muxes are switching.  All of this is happening at a very slow rate of one sample and one mux channel switch every 0.25 seconds.  I'd expect crosstalk to be sporadic too, the values I'm getting are very stable and uniform across the whole array of thermocouples.  I'm inclined to go with the mux/open-detection theory right now.

Comment: You are really cramping our ability to help by not supplying a full schematic and links to the chips. That tends to waste a lot of time and lead to sub-optimal results.  Seems like  you could remove the ground on the thermocouple (-) sides, if present and allow the thermocouple potentials to float up to the reference voltage thus disabling the open detection current path, but that's just a guess.

Comment: I think  that you should multiplexing both ends of thermocouples because of interaction of all wire "ground" of thermocouples. The both ends would have same "contact" metals for the two wires. When I talk about crosstalk, i intend here DC crosstalk, not because of switching channels.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, I'm sorry I cannot provide a schematic (it's a collaboration project which involves other people's intellectual property).  I was told that providing too many hyperlinks to things was frowned-upon because they can become "404" after a while.  I can't win :(

Comment: You said "the cold-junction seems to be entirely within the package body and there is no exposed thermal pad on the underside of the package".  The cold junction NEEDS TO BE the same temperature as the local temperature reference.  The local temperature reference is usually a good thermal resistor device.  The junction where the thermocouple wires 1st touch the circuit board needs to be of the same metal (if memory serves me correctly).  I don't think soldering is a good option.  As you may touch copper on one lead and you may not touch copper on the other.

Comment: @tobalt, I think you're probably right about the multiplexing being the issue.  Do you want to make that into an Answer and I'll give it a tick-mark.

Comment: Thanks for the offer @user882326721 but I will leave that to someone who can explain why the mux creates troubles, because the more I think of it, I don't understand why. LOL, it was just a gut feeling.

Comment: @st2000 That is something I had written into the comment box, then scrapped. Because I think it doesn't matter. If you go to another metal and back to copper on one lead the offsets would cancel if the junctions are at similar temperatures. Of course if there is a lot of heat around the MUX with large internal temperature differences.. Well it's all a bit vague.

Comment: @st2000, OK now that's something I can test easily :)  If I'm understanding you correctly, then I should not be soldering the thermocouples' wires to my PCB, I need simple wire-to-copper-pad pressure contact.  Is that right?

Comment: But that doesn't seem right because the whole of the rest of the circuit is just SMD chips soldered to the copper board anyway.  The cold junction is inside the ADC chip so it's not like I can treat it any different to any other chip on the design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your design is bad, but you can probably compensate for it in the firmware.**

I spent most of today dunking the probes in ice-water, then later heating them up with a 1 Ohm resistor attached to a PSU.

Turns out, the error is highly linear - at least between 0°C and about 50°C.

Simply subtracting 29.5°C from each sample basically solves the problem.

As previously discussed in the comments, it is likely that this error is indeed caused by the MAX4454 "1-of-2" mux chip (which is a CMOS device).  Additional (unwanted) leakage current is likely passing through the thermocouple which gives an artificially high temperature reading.

The design is obviously flawed.  I should have used a different way to multiplex these signals.  Better quality mux chips designed for low leakage etc.

But... it does raise a question, can this actually be a feature?  The MAX6675 according to the data sheet at least, only measures down to 0°C.  But since this accidental +29.5°C offset exists, perhaps this means that this board is now able to make measurements down to around -29.5°C (which the MAX6675 would **think** was 0°C).

That's a hypothetical question of course, if I made 10 of these devices, then they will probably all have different error offsets due to miniscule fabrication differences in the silicon chips on each board.

I'll try this tomorrow - refrigerating the probes down to -24°C or so (as cold as my freezer will go) and see if the readings track with my multimeter reference.

Pictures for fun:  The orange line is the average of four of the channels (two on each side of the "1-of-2" mux) the blue trace is the true temperature...

[image]

This one is each of those 4 channels individually over the same temperature range.  The separation of the lines on the right side is probably due to my failing to expose them all to the heat source evenly...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The multiplexer I use is much "better" than CD4051, so results are not probably the same.

Take into account that Ron for CD4051 @5V @25°C is about 400 Ohm and may vary a "bit" with temperature.
Leakage seems to be over ~ 100 nA to ~ 1000 nA. (100nA * 60k = 6 mV -> some degrees ...)

With the lack of schematic, I can make only a guess that "resistance's" are not "same value" with all thermocouples. I guess also that voltages are in order of mV.

Differences of voltage measured, on the 3 channels of interest, are in order of 500uV -> around 15 °C.

[image]